# Creating an object with a field based on the last one in django

Tags: django, concurrency, transactions, insert, locking

Consider the following Model:

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the following method that creates a ticket:

```
@transaction.atomic()
def create_ticket(self):
    last = Tickets.objects.order_by('created_at').last()
    next_number = 1 if last is None else last.number + 1
    new_ticket = Tickets.objects.create(number=next_number)
    return new_ticket
```

This fails if create_ticket is called concurrently, as the transaction won't have a reason to abort (no same record has been updated by multiple calls) but `last` will return repeated results on some runs. 
I'm aware of auto incrementing fields and they're not an option in this case, as there is extra logic in place that may cause next_number to reset to 0. I'm leaning towards finding a way to acquire a table lock but was hoping to find an easier way.

Comment: An atomic transaction is already safe from concurrent transaction. What is your question about it. It will never fail. Atomic transaction already locks the table so at a single instance of time only will transaction will be done

Comment: As I understand it, a transaction simply ensures that the changes inside the block will either all succeed or all fail. There is no table locking involved (hence it being an optimistic approach to concurrency). Consider the case where create_ticket is called twice, almost simultaneously, if the second one starts before the first one finishes, they'll both create tickets with the same number. In retrospective, I might need to wrap the whole thing in some sort of mutex to make this work